# Unable to access resources of dynamic-feature module

Tags: android, dynamic-feature, dynamic-delivery

I am trying to add the new Android dynamic delivery feature to my app, but my attempts to access the resources of the dynamic feature module keep failing.

The basic idea is to load a module with no code but a bunch of vector files as drawable resources.

I am able to load the module and even access the assets of given module, but I can't figure out how to access the resources.

```
         val res = context.createPackageContext(context.packageName, 0).also {
            SplitCompat.install(it)
         }.resources

         val assetsStream = res.assets.open("test.txt")
         val assetContent = assetsStream.bufferedReader()
                 .use {
                    it.readText()
                 }
         var iconResourceId = res.getIdentifier(stringIdentifier, IDENTIFIER_DRAWABLE, context.packageName)
```

As I said, I am able to read the text in the assets txt file, but I don't seem to find any drawables in the resources.

When i try to get drawables which i know are in the resources folder of the dynamic module i get a `ResourcesNotFoundException`

I've read through the Android Docs that are provided by Google but i'm not able to find detailed information about how to access a downloaded modules recources

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#access_installed_modules

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60227903/1749806

Comment: did you find what you were looking for? currently facing the same problem

Comment: No sadly not, we had to discard the idea of using a dynamic feature module for our use case because of that, and have not tried again since then.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by replacing the `packageName` for the feature-module package name, on the method of `res.getIdentifier(..., packageName)`

App package name: `com.example.my_app_package`
Feature's resources package name: `com.example.my_app_package.my_dynamic_feature`

I'm not sure exactly from where the value `my_dynamic_feature` is obtained, but the full package will not be the one that you defined on the module's build.gradle `applicationId` or AndroidManifest `package` property.